# The extension of measures

Tags: measure-theory

I know that if $A$ is any algebra of subsets of a set $X$ and if $\mu$ is a measure defined on A then this measure $\mu$ can be extended to a measure $\mu^*$ on a $\sigma$ algebra $A^*$ of subsets of X which contain $A$

I understand the above but not the stuff below.

If B is an arbitrary subset of $X$

Then $\mu^*(B)=$ inf $\sum^\infty_{j=1}  \mu(E_j)$

Where the infimum is extended over all sequences $(E_j)$ of sets in $A$ where

$B \subseteq \cup^\infty_{j=1} E_j$

What are the last three lines saying?

Comment: This is the definitions of $\mu*$

Comment: If the sequences $(E_j)$ are in A then what does B have to do with anything?

Comment: Should it not be $\mu^* (A)$ instead of $\mu^*(B)$?

Comment: B has to do in the condition  that " B is covered by the sequence E_i"

Comment: No it is correct as it is

Comment: @drhab why does their have to be an infimum?

Comment: **Every** subset of $[0,\infty]$ has an infimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the four lines are formal definition of outer measure, usually denoted by $\mu^*$. People often construct a measure from a outer measure. You can check this from the book by Royden, and many other standard real analysis books.

And I think you confuse the measure with the outer measure in your question. An outer measure usually is defined on a large algebra than measure and does not satisfy a good property that people want,i.e.,countable additive. So people select/construct a measure from that larger algebra, usually by Caratheodory condition.

Comment: $\mu^*(B) $ is the outer measure of B right?

Comment: Yes, if it is evaluated according to the definition.

Comment: Ok, is the definition saying: if B is covered by the sequence $E_j)$ then the outer measure of B is the infimum of the measure of the sequence $(E_j)$?

Comment: Yes, it says so.

Comment: Lastly why does it have to be an infimum?

Comment: Er, the definition says so. Actually outer measure is just an intermediate step. People always go further to construct measure out of outer measure. Of course this is not the only way to construct a measure. For example, people also do this by constructing an inner measure first.

Comment: @Aljabra It is not just one sequence we are talking about. There are lots of sequences in $A$ that cover $B$. So we get lots a values $\sum\mu E_j$. Together these values form a set and of this set we take the infimum.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the edit to your post, it clears a lot of things up. So essentially Caratheodory theorem is used to go from outer measure to a measure?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is the common way to construct a measure.

Answer (score 0):

Every sequence of sets $(E_j)_j$ in $\mathcal A$  that covers $B$ will induce a value $\sum\mu E_j$.

The collection of these values has an infimum and $\mu^{*}B$ is defined to be that infimum.